# Access to jOOQ integration test source code

Tags: integration-testing, jooq

The commercial editions of jOOQ provide source code access. I've seen the "integration tests" mentioned a few times in the jOOQ-related documentation and community discussions. Never a link to them though. Are the integration test suites accessible to people buying commercial edition?

I believe having access to and run test cases would greatly help with understanding how to use jOOQ topics in which documentation is not enough for me to understand specific features.

I searched the source code of the commercial jOOQ edition for occurrences of "test", "assert" or other common Java testing phrases, but I only found results in jOOQ Examples, which seem to be basic usage examples rather than integration tests I suppose jOOQ to have.

Googling didn't work for me (probably) due to the sources being exclusive to the commercial editions.

Is jOOQ integration test suites source code available?

Comment: GPT (version 4!) is quite good at helping generate jooq code. Getting it to help you takes about the same amount of effort as getting answers on SO: explain your problem in prose and, if possible, give a sample of the equivalent SQL. Access to the V4 model via ChatGPT requires the paid tier - but you could try using Bing, if you're willing to setup MS account, browser, etc. It does understand jooq 3.19 constructs, but I had to poke it a bit to force it to use the newer way of doing things.

Comment: @Shorn: You should really blog about this! I'd love to see some examples of successful translations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jOOQ's integration tests aren't available to anyone, including paying customers. They're completely closed source.

But you're not specifically looking for tests, but rather for more detailed examples, I suspect? There's a demo here, which probably answers most of your questions:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/demo

The demo is much better suited than the integration tests anyway, given how many weird and quirky edge cases the tests cover, whereas the demo aims at showing how to use jOOQ, instead.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about the reason. I thought it'd be easier to search through the tests because writing documentation is never ending story, but I 100% understand your reasons for closing those sources. 
Thank you very much for the demo link, It'll help with many questions! I wonder why I didn't notice it earlier. 
For features not covered there I presume I just need to ask on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @NorbertKawinski: Yes, Stack Overflow is great for these things, or you can create a feature request on the demo add more demos about features: https://github.com/jOOQ/demo/issues (e.g. policies are still due)